# Ubuntu login screen wallpaper switches to match user wallpaper now. How to disable?

Tags: login, screen, desktop-background

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu Tweak to change the login screen wallpaper. Somewhere along the way, the login screen wallpaper now matches the user wallpaper background, overriding the change I set in Ubuntu Tweak. How can I change it back so that the user wallpaper isn't shown on the login screen? I've had this happen before on a different machine and I cannot for the life of me work out how to change it back. I used the `dconf-editor` to check the settings under ubuntu-greeter and it's correct, but the login screen always switches to the user wallpaper on boot now, although I see my Ubuntu Tweak set login screen wallpaper briefly before it changes to the user wallpaper. Little help?